# Access software and files?

Tags: networking

I'm interested in buying a Raspberry Pi 3b, as I see many possibilities with it.
Nevertheless, I would like to ask one specific question. Does this device allow me to use softwares (just like Photoshop) and files from my PC directly on another PC?
This would be really useful in my job.

Thank you for your answer.
Yours sincerely,

Timothy

Comment: Photoshop , Microsoft Office and Windows Games will never work on a Pi.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of software available for the Pi, but it's not a substitute for a PC: it doesn't have the RAM or the GPU to run "heavy" apps. That being said, you can setup network shared folders on the Pi and make them accessible from your PC.

The niche where the Pi really shines is for low power (it runs on about 10W) deployments where you need to interact with sensors or buttons, or perform automated tasks over networks.